# Pointer as function parameter in C is NULL

Tags: c, pointers

Pardon any ignorance - I'm relatively new to C. I have the below function:

```
int get_fingerprint_device(struct fp_dev *device) {
    struct fp_dscv_dev **devices;
    int rtn;

    if (!(devices = fp_discover_devs())) {
        rtn = -1;
    }
    else {
        if (!(device = fp_dev_open(*devices))) {
            rtn = -2;
        }
        else {
            if (device) {
                printf("Device OK\n");
            }

            rtn = 1;
        }

        fp_dscv_devs_free(devices);
    }

    return rtn;
}
```

And I have a main() as follows:

```
int main(void)
{
    // Vars
    struct fp_dev *device;
    struct fp_print_data **print_data;
    struct fp_img **img;
    int err;

    // Init libfprint
    fp_init();

    // Get the first fingerprint device
    if ((err = get_fingerprint_device(device)) < 0) { // Errorz
        if (err == -1) {
            error("No devices found");
        }
        else if (err == -2) {
            error("Couldn't open the device");
        }

        return 1;
    }

    if (device == NULL) {
        printf("No\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        printf("Yes\n");
        return 0;
    }

    fp_enroll_finger_img(device, print_data, img);

    // Deinit libfprint
    fp_exit();

    return 0;
}
```

The result when run is that it first prints "Device OK" and then prints "No".

Why is it that device is a valid pointer in get_fingerprint_device() but not when back in main()? My understanding is that I should be using a double pointer here such that the inner pointer value can change and be propagated back to main()... however the implementation has so far eluded me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `device` is passed into `get_fingerprint_device` by value. In other words, the function gets its own copy of `device` pointer. Then it assigns something to it, but the change is not visible outside that function, so once it returns, the caller (in this case `main`) does not see any change. If you want this to work, you have to pass pointer to pointer into `get_fingerprint_device` function (i.e. `struct fp_dev **device`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My implementation is thus: https://gist.github.com/phil-lavin/d9c7e8f2ce5f6e3cf3e6 however it causes a segfault on the line that assigns the fp_dev_open(). Any hints?

Comment: This may be unrelated as fp_dev_open(*devices) segfaults also. I'll investigate.

Answer (score 0):

You're a little confused about passing pointers in C - currently you're just passing "wild" (unallocated) pointers. You should change:

```
struct fp_dev *device;
```

to:

```
struct fp_dev device;
```

and change:

```
if ((err = get_fingerprint_device(device)) < 0)
```

to:

```
if ((err = get_fingerprint_device(&device)) < 0)
```

Comment: The first change (the struct not being a pointer) produces this in GCC. error: storage size of device isn't known in GCC

Comment: You're probably not #including a required header. Or it may be an opaque pointer. It's hard to debug your code without seeing all the relevant headers etc.